# How can I identify which Keurig machines have Keurig 2.0 DRM?

Tags: keurig

To be more specific, is there a particular label or marking on the package that will indicate if a given Keurig machine uses K-cup label DRM?  (Or is a better term Coffee Rights Management (CRM)?)

Comment: Hmm. Is this really a question which belongs to coffee? It sounds a little bit more to hack your coffee machine.

Comment: @Tim it reads more like a way to tell products apart so a consumer can make an informed choice to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears specific models are under the Keurig 2.0 label.  The K250, K350, K450, K550 will be clearly marked Keurig 2.0, which use the label DRM.